# Комментарии в intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Как закомментировать выделенную часть кода ?

Comment: `ctrl + /`.....

Answer (score 2):

Комбинация клавиш ctrl+shift+/ закомментирует выделенную часть кода в блок /* */.
Комбинация клавиш ctrl+/ закомментирует все выделенные строки путем добавления в начало каждой строки //.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+ / — Комментирование строки с помощью //.

CTRL + SHIFT + / — Комментирование выделенного блока кода с помощью /**/

Повторное использование этих комбинаций убирает комментарии.